# Is it possible to view previous API versions of Lightning Web Components developer guide documentation?

Tags: lightning-web-components

At the time of this posting, the link to one of the more historical documentation pages or "Developer Guides" for Lightning Web Components is hosted at

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lwc.meta/lwc/lwc_intro.htm

There, you will see the familiar page layout for documentation, however for LWC the documentation exists at another location entirely. Again, at the time of this message those locations are:

Unauthenticated: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc

Authenticated: [salesforce-instance]/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc

Pertaining to the "classic" developer guide page for LWC (the first link above), the links to the new documentation page do not change when selecting an API version. In my experience with aura components as well as Apex, new release API updates can and will inevitably break existing implementations. Referencing different API versions is often helpful when resolving these issues.

**It does not make any sense to me why Lightning Web Components metadata files have a** `<apiVersion>XX.0</apiVersion>` **tag if the only apiVersion documentation viewable is the latest release.**

How does the component api versions of LWC differ from aura lightning components, Apex, or other component source files?

If someone can provide insight into the what/why/how of the deviation from other developer documentation pages, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when it happened, but the docs page for LWC was updated recently. Version-specific docs now appears in the left panel.

[image: API version display in LWC docs]